# Android Actionbar Activity convert to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi guys I'am having errors with my fragment, because i need to convert this Activity:

I need the variables the content view the function to put in that fragment above need help :(

```
public class Cardiology extends ActionBarActivity {

private final String TAG = "Cardiology";
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
TextView word;
TextView mean;
AutoCompleteTextView actv;
Cursor cursor;
Button search;
int flag = 0;
ListView ls;
ArrayList<String> dataword;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardiology);

    ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewortho);





    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        dbhelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "can't read/write file ");
        Toast.makeText(this, "error loading data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    dbhelper.openDataBase();





    String[] from = {"english_word"};
    int[] to = {R.id.text};
    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewr);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.singalline, null, from, to);
    // This will provide the labels for the choices to be displayed in the AutoCompleteTextView
    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {

            return cursor.getString(1);
        }
    });
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            cursor = null;
            int count = constraint.length();
            if (count >= 1) {
                String constrains = constraint.toString();
                cursor = dbhelper.queryc(constrains);

            }

            return cursor;
        }
    });


    actv.setAdapter(adapter);

    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Buttonr);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Main Activity", "Search button was clicked");
            searchData();
        }
    });

    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            flag = 1;
            Log.d("Main Activity", "actv list item was ckicked");
        }
    });

    actv.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == 0) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == 0x42) {
                    searchData();
                    actv.dismissDropDown();
                    hideKeyBoard();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("My Activity", "Item in Lower list is clicked");
            String word = dataword.get(position);
            startMeaning(word);


        }
    });

}
```

to a

```
Fragment:public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment{

public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




}


public View onViewCreated(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cardiology, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Need Help Please :(`

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) is deprecated. You must use the constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)

Comment: What is the error? Post logcat if you are getting any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take out code from onCreate from your activity and put everything in Fragments onCreteView Method. Take out all global variable from activity and put in fragment

Change this to getActivity() in the fragment.
Also change layout.singalline to R.layout.singalline

Answer (score 0):

Adding getActivity() and view for every "findid" solve my problem.